# Is this the correct way to nest an async function inside of a promise?

Tags: javascript

Looking at other questions, it wasn't clear what the best thing to do here was.

I need to call function B from function A. However function B makes several async calls and I would prefer to use async/await instead of chaining promises. The problem becomes, I need to tell function A to wait for all the awaits in function B to be done.

Here is what I did that does work, I'm wondering if it's an anti-pattern.

To accomplish this, Function A (async) calls Function B which is a promise that contains async Function C.

```js
    const functionA = async () => {

       await functionB().catch(err => console.error(err));
       console.log(' ALL DONE ');
    }

    const functionB = () => {
       return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => { 

           const functionC = async () => {
               const var1 = await make_databaseCall();
               const var2 = await make_different_DatabaseCall();
               if(!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

               const what_I_need = var1 + var2;
               return resolve();
           }

           //Calling Function C and returning what FuncC returns (resolve()) to Function B

           return functionC();

       });
    }
```

Comment: I think this is a good use case for `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mixture of `Promises` and await/async is not necessary in this case.  And the nesting of `functionC()` is not needed.  I think you could reduce it to:

```
const functionA = async () => {
   try {       
       await functionB();
   } catch {...}
}

const functionB = async () => {
   const var1 = await make_databaseCall();
   const var2 = await make_different_DatabaseCall();
   if(!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

   return var1 + var2;
}
```

Additionally, if you can do the two db calls in parallel, you'll want to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
const [var1, var2] = await Promise.all([
    make_databaseCall(), 
    make_different_DatabaseCall()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that returns a promise, it is pointless to wrap it in a `Promise` constructor.

If you have a function that does nothing except call another function and return its return value, then it is pointless to have that function (unless you are playing games with arguments).

So just make `functionC` into `functionB`. You'll get the same result.

```
const functionA = async () => {
  await functionB().catch(err => console.error(err));
  console.log(' ALL DONE ');
};

const functionB = async () => {
  const var1 = await make_databaseCall();
  const var2 = await make_different_DatabaseCall();
  if (!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

  return var1 + var2;
};
```

That said, since your second database call doesn't appear to depend on the result of the first one, you should probably let them run in *parallel* instead of serially.

Use `Promise.all` to acheive that.

```
const functionA = async () => {
  await functionB().catch(err => console.error(err));
  console.log(' ALL DONE ');
};

const functionB = async () => {
  const [var1, var2] = await Promise.all([make_databaseCall(), make_different_DatabaseCall()]);
  if (!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');
  return = var1 + var2;
};
```

And a benefit of `await` and `async` is that you can use traditional `try/catch` blocks, so do so:

```
const functionA = async () => {
  try {
    await functionB();
    console.log(' ALL DONE ');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err));
  }
};

const functionB = async () => {
  const [var1, var2] = await Promise.all([make_databaseCall(), make_different_DatabaseCall()]);
  if (!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');
  return = var1 + var2;
};
```

Comment: In your solution, isn't functionB NOT a promise? so isn't `await functionB` going to do nothing?

Comment: @Badrush — `functionB` is declared with the `async` keyword so it returns a Promise.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you're asking:

```
const functionA = async () => {
  try {
    await functionB();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  console.log(' ALL DONE ');
}


const functionB = async () => {
  const var1 = await make_databaseCall();
  const var2 = await make_different_DatabaseCall();

  if (!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

  return var1 + var2;
}
```

Comment: To help you understand how promises and async-await are related, try this from your repl:

`const foo = async () => 5;`

`console.log(foo());`
`console.log(Promise.resolve(5));`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `return new Promise` if you make `functionB` an async function:

```js
const functionB = async () => {
   const var1 = await make_databaseCall();
   const var2 = await make_different_DatabaseCall();
   if(!var2) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

   const what_I_need = var1 + var2;
};
```

If you want `var1` and `var2` to run in parralel, you can use `Promise.all()`:

```js
const functionB = async () => {
    const vars = await Promise.all([
        make_databaseCall(),
        make_different_DatabaseCall()
    ]);

    if(!vars[2]) throw Error('var2 is invalid!');

    const what_I_need = vars[1] + vars[2];
};
```